# Python crashing while launching matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, ipython

I am using python 3.4 in my windows OS all on 32 bit. While launching matplotlib.pyplot python is crashing with error as python is not working.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,1,2])
```

After running above code in ipython notebook getting error as "Python has stopped working" as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanx in advance for reply.

Comment: could it be similar to this: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8921#issuecomment-151046708

Comment: @AlexL I am using python 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 2.5.0 (32bit) on windows os. I am using matplotlib version 1.5.1. In the link of github solution was given as to add following lines of code after importing matplotlib                                                       mpl.rcParams['backend'] = "qt4agg"
mpl.rcParams['backend.qt4'] = "PySide"  . But this dint help my cause, can you help me identifying reason for crash.

Comment: As per link given by you it is bug with python 3.4 and is resolved in python 3.5. Although I am using python 3.5 , still I am encountering this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now resolved. Update matplotlib to latest 2.0.0 version.

```
pip install matplotlib --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Update matplotlib to latest version:

```
pip3 install matplotlib --upgrade
```